# Setting context variable in Watson Assistant from an entity that uses pattern

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am trying to build a chatbot that implemnts a simple calculator, using Watson assistant. It needs to recognize simple math expressions  , e.g "1+2". I set up an intent called #simple_math that recognizes phrases like "what is 1+1", which works fine.
[image: intention definition]

I then created an entity called @mathexp that uses a pattern (regexp) to identify the expression part:
[image: entity definition]
Which also seems to fire correctly when a simple expression is detected. But when I go to the node where I try to assign the value identified using @mathexp.literal, it never gets set. I go into the node called "math", the assistant recognized #simple_math and @mathexp, but the context variable $Mexp (which I am setting to `"<? @mathexp.literal ?>"`) is always blank
[image: tryign to set context variable]

What am I missing

Comment: How do you know it is not set? Did you check the context editor (Try it) or print it as response? Are you sure that the node is visited?

Comment: Yes to both - I   checked it in the "manage context ' debug box and it is blank, as well as trying to print it out in the node. I know the node - there is text there that the bot prints, and I can also see it visited using "try it"

Comment: I would try `input.text` with a second variable, just to be sure.

Comment: I think the issue is with the pattern itself- it seems to match anything - so @mathexp is recognized as blank from a previous node